# How to link each field in a database table to a new unique table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a ledger application in Java using MySQL as the database.The database structure is something like this:

**Table: Accounts**
  --Account_No --Account_Holder--Address--Phone--

**Table Ledger**(This exists for each Account)
  --Date-- Particulars -- Debit --- Credit -- Dr/Cr-- Bal

an example of such a database would be:
--Account_No --Account_Holder--Address--Phone--
   10001          -----------Joe Smith-------XXXYYYXXX--9283910203
   10002        -----------Jamie Mackie------YYYYXXYYS--9992929292
and so on..

--Date--Particulars--Debit--Credit--Dr/Cr--Bal
(This table belongs to account no 10001)
  may 5 ---  Prod XYZ --   290--    500 ----------    -     210
  May 8---  Cash Pmt--- 210     -      -      ------------------0

and similar for each account...

Now the problem is that each account will have a ledger table and for each new account I need to create a table but that doesnt seem right. Is there any other way to do it? Or I am looking at it all wrong. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Normal way to do it is you have a single ledger table with a column to mark it as which account that row belongs to.

Multiple tables containing the same info is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thank you @Kickstart.I did further more research on how I can maintain common ledger entries in a single ledger table and I found a pretty good basic example here [link] http://arachnoid.com/MySQL/relational_databases.html. Your comment helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem. Having had to deal with systems with multiple tables (or databases) storing the same info, and then having to loop around them all to get aggregated data at some point I would say it is something to be avoided.